# Path to TlbExp/TlbImp during build with MsBuild (VS2015)

Tags: c#, msbuild, alm

I switched some solutions to build with the newest framework and toolsets on a clean buildmachine with only VS2015 and the buildagent.

For all the vc-projects the pathvariable "TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory" fit my needs. And it looks like this:

```
"$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)tlbimp.exe" $(TargetPath) /verbose /strictref /asmversion=$(Version) /out:$(DropLocation)
```

But for the c#-projects i cant find any solution. The previous solution looked like this:

```
"$(WindowsSDKDir)\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\tlbexp" $(TargetPath) /out:$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName).tlb
```

But the buildmachine doesnt know "WindowsSDKDir" or "FrameworkSDKdir" and I would prefer to need as little as possible customization.

I cannot imagine that I am the only one with this issue, so i hope to find a someone who allready solved this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that the best solution for my needs is, to install Windows SDK on the buildmachine and use TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory for c# and c++ projects.

Answer (score 1):

Im using:

```
call "$(VS140COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" 
tlbexp.exe "$(TargetPath)" /out:"$(SolutionDir)CommonFiles\$(TargetName).tlb"
```

This will work not only inside Visual Studio but also if you build using msbuild...

I would not recommend to use:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

since it will work only inside Visaul Stuio but would fail with msbuild...

Make sure that you have installed Windows SDK (part of Visual Studio).